pgfplot using second block of data separated by 2 blank rows
I want to use pgfplots in latex to plot data from a file that was formatted for use with index function of gnuplot. The data file has sets of x,y columns separated by two blank rows (gnuplot format).
10  10              
20  18      
30  36      


10  11
20  20
30  41

With gnuplot, I can do
plot 'data.dat' index 0 u 1:1 with p lw 2 pt 4 ps 1 lc rgb 'red' t 'One, \
'' index 1 u 1:2 with p lw 2 pt 5 ps 1 lc rgb 'blue' t 'Two'

Without rewriting the data file in a different format, can I plot this data format with pgfplots?
Is there something in pgfplots that is equivalent to index of gnuplot? The pgfplot index refers to column numbers in a multicolumn data, not the second block of data, to the best of my understanding.

Welcome. // I suggest to add a screenshot from your gnuplot result for reference. Thank you

Unchanged data format: most likely - NO. Equivalent to index: YES. I suggest to spend some time and trials on https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/ .

I think the index does  refer to the blocks, that is index 0 depicts the first three lines of code and index 1 depicts the second three lines after the two blank lines. At least if I plot this using gnuplot I get a diagram that represents the data according to this logic. Note that there is a ' missing iin your gnuplot code (after 'One).

To my understanding index 0 u 1:2 means: use first block (with index 0), within this block use column 1 as x and column 2 as y.

First, let's look at how gnuplot parses things. As far as I understand index 0 u 1:2 means: look at the first (zero-indexed) block and use column 1 as x and column 2 as y values. This can be shown by plotting the data using the gnuplottex package:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor, gnuplottex}

\begin{filecontents}[noheader]{data.dat}
10  10              
20  18      
30  36      


10  11
20  20
30  41
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex]
plot 'data.dat' index 0 u 1:2 with p lw 2 pt 4 ps 1 lc rgb 'red'  t 'One', \
             '' index 1 u 1:2 with p lw 2 pt 4 ps 1 lc rgb 'blue' t 'Two'
\end{gnuplot}

\end{document}



This means: We just need to append each row with an index that identifies the block we are currently in.
It is probably easier to do this with some other software, but you can let TeX convert the file and append an index column to each row. You can then filter the data using this approach.
The following reads in the file and appends an index (an integer starting from 1) which is increased if two consecutive blank lines are met. The new data is written to the file data_index.dat which you can then read in with PGFPlots.
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{filecontents}[noheader]{data.dat}
10  10              
20  18      
30  36      


10  11
20  20
30  41
\end{filecontents}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \iow_now:Nn { Ne }
\int_new:N \l_csnl_gnutopgf_index_int
\int_set:Nn \l_csnl_gnutopgf_index_int { 1 }
\bool_new:N \l_csnl_gnutopgf_blank_line_bool
\bool_set_false:N \l_csnl_gnutopgf_blank_line_bool
\ior_new:N \g_csnl_gnutopgf_input_ior
\ior_open:Nn \g_csnl_gnutopgf_input_ior { data.dat }
\iow_new:N \g_csnl_gnutopgf_output_iow
\iow_open:Nn \g_csnl_gnutopgf_output_iow { data_index.dat }
\iow_now:Nn \g_csnl_gnutopgf_output_iow { index ~ x ~ y }
\ior_str_map_inline:Nn \g_csnl_gnutopgf_input_ior {
    \bool_if:NT \l_csnl_gnutopgf_blank_line_bool {
        \str_if_empty:nT {#1} {
            \int_incr:N \l_csnl_gnutopgf_index_int
        }
        \bool_set_false:N \l_csnl_gnutopgf_blank_line_bool
    }
    \str_if_empty:nTF {#1} {
        \bool_set_true:N \l_csnl_gnutopgf_blank_line_bool
    } {
        \bool_set_false:N \l_csnl_gnutopgf_blank_line_bool
        \iow_now:Ne \g_csnl_gnutopgf_output_iow { 
            \int_eval:n { \l_csnl_gnutopgf_index_int } ~ #1
        }
    }
}
\ior_close:N \g_csnl_gnutopgf_input_ior
\iow_close:N \g_csnl_gnutopgf_output_iow
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
    only index/.style={
        x filter/.code={
            \edef\tempa{\thisrow{index}}
            \edef\tempb{#1}
            \ifx\tempa\tempb\else
                \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
        }
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend pos=north west]
    \addplot table[x=x, y=y, only index=1]{data_index.dat};
    \addlegendentry{One}
    \addplot table[x=x, y=y, only index=2]{data_index.dat};
    \addlegendentry{Two}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


